# Segmentation Fault occurred when using function inside a switch/ifelse statement in a c language

Tags: c, file

I'm new to c programming. I'd like to use a function inside a switch or if else statement. But after I run the program. It immediately show me segmentation fault and exit the program. Below is my code. Please run through it

```
void phone1();
int main()
{
    int option;
    while (1) {
        printf("1) Option 1 \n");
        printf("2) Option 2 \n");
        scanf("%d", &option);
        switch (option) {
        case 1:
            phone1();
            break;
        case2:
            phone2();
            break;
        default:
            printf("Error");
            break;
        }
        while (1);
        return 0;
    }
}

void phone1()
{
    FILE* fi;
    char value[100];
    fi = fopen("phone.txt", "r");
    fseek(fi, -10, SEEK_END);
    fgets(value, 100, fi);
    printf("%s", value);
    fclose(fi);
}
```

And here is my phone.txt file

```
phone1 John 192901
phone2 Joseph 858201
phone3 Jay 757279
phone4 Teddy 847291
phone5 Ed 469274
```

I tried the function outside switch statement inside int main() and everything works fine. So I don't know what cause the segmentation fault to fail within the switch statement.

Comment: There is a `while(1);` after your switch statement, what does it do?

Comment: Use a debugger. It will tell you immediately and exactly which line of code triggers the seg fault. That is the minimum info you should have already collected and posted in the question. Also, please provide complete code as a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). At least `phone2`definition  is missing. And code does not look like it will even compile as there are mismatched braces.

Comment: "It **immediately** show me segmentation fault and exit the program." Hmm.. are you saying that the program crash is before the input part (aka `scanf`) ?

Comment: Sorry, what I meant to say is it crash after I input a number.

Comment: You should check the value of `fi` before use

Comment: ok... and I guess your input is a `1` - correct?

Comment: My guess is that `fi` is NULL, i.e. the "phone.txt" wasn't found. Probably, the program is looking for it in another location than you expect. Try to write the full path to the file.

Comment: `fi = fopen("phone.txt", "r");` --> `fi = fopen("phone.txt", "r"); if (fi == NULL) { printf("Open failed\n"); return;}`

Comment: You are really not going to write one function per line to retrieve each of the different lines are you? That's when it is time to re-think your logic. Why not pass the line number to read from the file as an argument. Then you can read the value entered by the user and get that line from the file.

Comment: "Please run through it" --> Posted code doe not compile without error.  Post input used and a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to add a closing brace for the `while` loop block and to omit the one in the end.

Second, you shouldn't `fseek()` to a negative. What did you try to achieve?

Your function opens a file, and reads the first 100 characters into value. Then, it prints them. I think i get what you are trying to achieve here, so this is an example of roughly how I'd do it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{   
    FILE *fptr = fopen("contacts.txt", "r");
    int contact;
    char name[100]; // or whatever size you need
    int number;
    char c = 'a';
    scanf("%d", &contact);
    ++contact; // to use 1-based numbering
    for (int i = 0; i < contact && c != EOF; ++i)
        while ((c = fgetc(fptr)) != EOF && c != '\n');
    // safely jumps to contact-th line
    fscanf(fptr, "%s %d", name, &number);
    printf("%s\t%d\n", name, number);
    return 0;
}
```

Which would need a `contacts.txt` in the form:

```
Ed 1234
Emma 7890
```

You could also make it check how many contact entries/lines are there, and bound-check the input.

Comment: Missing check that [fopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) did not fail

Comment: When `char` is _unsigned_ and end-of-file occurs, `while ((c = fgetc(fptr)) != EOF && c != '\n');` is an infinite loop.  Use `int ch;`

Comment: "Second, you shouldn't fseek() to a negative. " --> Code attempts to seek 10 from the end with `fseek(fi, -10, SEEK_END);`.  It is not the strange.